# Get the list of scenarios with their status in a java object

Tags: karate

Is there a way to get a list of all the scenarios executed with their status (passed or failed) in a java object.

I know that we have JSON and XML reports, but I just need a simple list of scenarios along with their status without having to parse any other file.

From what I found in the documentation, we can use the following code

```
KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, "target/surefire-reports");
```

But stats has only the number of failed scenarios with their execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use the `karate.info` API, look at the last row of this table: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object

And you have the `afterScenario` and `afterFeature` hooks. I think if you instantiate an empty JSON array `[]` as a variable in the `Background` using `callonce`, you should be able to `* eval myArray.push(info)` into it after each `Scenario`. Or try create a Java singleton and collect everything, that may be easier. Personally I think attempting to parse the Cucumber JSON may be the 'right' thing to do, but hey.

You may need to upgrade to 0.7.0.RC7 which is available. Please refer to the upgrade guide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Upgrading-To-0.7.0